# How to get reference to projection HTML element from parent component?

Tags: angular

Inside parent component:

```
<app-parent>
   <div class="projection"></div>
</app-parent>
```

How to get referens to HTMLElement inside `app-parent-component`?

As result I need to get DOM element `<div class="projection"></div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<div #projection class="projection"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
@ViewChild('projection') projection: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.projection.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: What If I dont have reference `#projection`. Just this `<app-parent>
   <div></div>
</app-parent>`

Comment: Why not `@ContentChild `?

Comment: `Argument of type 'ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'.`